# QGIS - Export lossless PDF not available

Tags: qgis, pdf

I'm trying to save a PDF map using QGIS 3.16.9, but for some reason on one of my computer, the choice of the lossless export is not available.

Even with a new QGIS project, this particular option is greyed out, so I don't think it's a project setting that has to be changed.
[image]

Comment: The option of lossless pdf is available in exporting a layout; I don't see it for exporting a view.

Comment: I'm trying to export a layout.

Comment: Would you be willing to try upgrading your QGIS to at least 3.22? I think some of the compression settings are tied to the version of Qt that goes with QGIS.

Comment: Late reply, after I updated QGIS to 3.28, the option is now available, so the Qt version might be the problem here indeed.